# Unable to use require in VSCode extension renderer process

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to use import in the script I loaded in HTML, but the error occurs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
```

I am trying to order my code with classes in typescript. Does that mean everything I write for the renderer process in vscode extensions has to be in one js file?

New to extension programming, any help appreciated.

Here is how I build HTML:

```
        webviewPanel.webview.html = getHtmlTemplate(webviewPanel, this.context);
```

and my HTML looks like:

```
export function getHtmlTemplate(webviewPanel: vscode.WebviewPanel, context: vscode.ExtensionContext) : string {
    const scriptUri = webviewPanel.webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        context.extensionUri, 'out', 'main.js'));

    const styleResetUri = webviewPanel.webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        context.extensionUri, 'media', 'reset.css'));

    const styleVSCodeUri = webviewPanel.webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        context.extensionUri, 'media', 'vscode.css'));

    const styleMainUri = webviewPanel.webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        context.extensionUri, 'media', 'style.css'));

    // Use a nonce to whitelist which scripts can be run
    const nonce = getNonce();
    return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!--
        Use a content security policy to only allow loading images from https or from our extension directory,
        and only allow scripts that have a specific nonce.
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src ${webviewPanel.webview.cspSource}; style-src ${webviewPanel.webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="${styleResetUri}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="${styleVSCodeUri}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="${styleMainUri}" rel="stylesheet" />

        <title>Cat Scratch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="split left">
                <h1>Story Editor</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="split right">
                <h1>Story Blueprint</h1>
                <div class="nodes">
                    <div class="add-button">
                        <button>Create Node</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <canvas id = "_canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script nonce="${nonce}"> var exports = {}; </script>
        <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>`;   
}
```

I am writing main.ts which will be compile into main.js, and I would like to use import in main.ts

Comment: give a small example of what your files look like, which HTML in the extension (WebView)? Rendering process, what do you mean? Nothings runs TypeScript, TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript.

Comment: @rioV8 I added an example, thanks for reminding

Comment: since when can you do `import` in a web page, use `script` tags in the html page of the code you like to import